# How to choose server region?

Tags: cloud

How can I determine which server region to have a user connect to? If I have servers in 5 different regions, should I just send out 5 pings and choose the server that got back the fastest?

Comment: You should at least explain what it is you're serving, what options you've researched yourself, etc.

Comment: I'm looking to launch a game in other countries and was considering just having all users connect to American servers, but was concerned about latency. I was thinking about just having the users select which server they want to try, but I am really at a loss on how to handle routing users.

Comment: In short, yes, but this is more a programming question than anything related to server operation. Look up "Gamespy" and "Server browsing" for reference material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many methods, from using different hostnames in different domains `www.example.eu`, `www.example.au`, `www.example.cn` and the "common" `www.example.com` or by using subdomains such as `www.[eu | au | cn].example.com` and setting a cookie that redirects users to a near location, either based on a metric or a stored preference.

The metrics are usually the client ip-address in combination with a IP location database, but also browser accept language, the HTML5 location header or commonly used. 
Actively letting your  server determine which is the optimal server for a specific user by letting each server ping the user's IP-address is uncommon, but may work for your use-case.

More common is using anycast DNS that will direct DNS queries to a DNS server  that is (network-wise) nearest to a user and let that nearest  DNS server resolve www.example.com to the IP-address of the server that is nearest.  Many cloud (DNS) providers provide such a service as part of their offering.